# MySQL left join with exists subquery returns more rows than it should

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database and SQL query with subqueries.

I'm 100% sure that the table `s_k_p` has only one row where `s_k_p.season_id = 2` and `s_k_p.user_id = k_i.user_id`.

Anyway, the problem is that `LEFT JOIN s_k_p AS skp2` part returns 10 rows. As said, it should return only one row.

```
SELECT skp2.season_id AS invalid_status_id
FROM comp_i
  INNER JOIN k_i ON k_i.ilmo_id = comp_i.id

  LEFT JOIN s_k_p
    ON s_k_p.user_id = k_i.user_id
       AND s_k_p.season_id = 4

  LEFT JOIN s_k_p AS skp2
    ON skp2.user_id = k_i.user_id
       AND EXISTS (
         SELECT *
           FROM s_k_p
           WHERE s_k_p.season_id = 2
             AND s_k_p.user_id = k_i.user_id
       )
WHERE comp_i.comp_id = ?
ORDER BY k_i.id ASC
```

The table s_k_p has the following rows:

```
season_id | user_id
1 | 25
1 | 459
2 | 459
3 | 459
3 | 9999
4 | 459
4 | 758
```

The second row is the only one where `s_k_p.season_id = 2` and `s_k_p.user_id = k_i.user_id` should be true.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Alternatively, set up an example on SQL Fiddle or Rextester.

Comment: I vote for Rextester :-)

Comment: `EXISTS` returns either `true` or `false`, regardless if there's one row or 100000 rows. You probably want to use `AND s_k_p.season_id = 2` (similar to the previous join) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query probably is correct in returning 10 rows if there are 10 rows for the USER in the S_K_P table because THAT is the left-join.

You have your exist to a SECONDARY level to the same S_K_P table but INCLUDING the Season_ID = 2.

If what you care about is only if it exists for the same user, season 2, then change to

```
 LEFT JOIN s_k_p AS skp2
    ON skp2.user_id = k_i.user_id
    AND skp2.season_id = 2
```